# Poedit ASCII errors ( Wordpress )

Tags: translation

I am trying to translate a wordpress theme to Arabic and I am totally new to the translation field.

I followed the steps in this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127917/generating-po-mo-translating-files-from-scratch-in-a-wordpress-theme) and I added a new domain to my theme instead of hard coding everything .

1. I loaded my text domain in the functions file :

   ```
   add_action('after_setup_theme', 'lanugage_domain');
   function lanugage_domain(){
       load_theme_textdomain('users', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
   }
   ```
2. I added every text in the theme with __() or _e() function for example

`text` --> `__('text','users')`

3. I created a new PO file in my language directory with the name of `users.pot` with Poedit with the **`UTF-8`** Charset

   3.1 - When I started scanning the files and error appeared to me

   ```
     01/11/2015 08:50:54: C:\Program Files (x86)\Poedit\GettextTools\bin\xgettext.exe: Non-ASCII comment at or before js/jquery.dialogBox.js:14.
     01/11/2015 08:50:54:                                                              Please specify the source encoding through --from-code
     01/11/2015    08:50:54:                                                              
     01/11/2015 08:50:54: Entries in the catalogue are probably incorrect.
     01/11/2015 08:50:54: Updating the catalogue failed. Click on 'Details >>' for details.
   ```

I didn't knew from where this error came from because I am using the UTF-8 charset, did I miss something ?

Comment: In the concern of translation, you need to put only English characters in the theme within any gettext function. And using a tool like POEdit or EasyPO you can then convert them to any language. I think the problem is occurring because you've already put any Arabic text somewhere in the theme, and it seems it's in a `.js` file. Try the [Theme Check](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/) plugin to find any Non-ASCII character in your theme, and fix it first.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam For the response, I didn't add any Arabic letter to my project yet I tried Installing the plugin (polylang) it may added the Arabic letter somewhere (maybe) but now it is deactivated .

And when I add an English text to my code I add it like this `<?php echo __("text text","users"); ?>`

Comment: Please use Theme Check with "Suppress Info" unchecked.

Comment: What does said file at line specified contains precisely?

Comment: Oh, I checked the line the error was pointing to, it was on Chinese letter in a javascript comment, I didn't see it in the first place :)

Comment: But now I have my constant WPLANG set to ar and I have `users-ar.po` and `user-ar.mo` in my language directory and nothing is changed. I tried changing it from the dashboard settings but it change the whole wordpress language without including my translation strings in the page, the is a note under the language changing bar in the dashboard settings `Note: The WPLANG constant in your wp-config.php file is no longer needed. ` I think it cause the problem, what should I do please ?

Answer (score -1):

in poeditor go to file->preferences->extractors->javascript->edit and change language JavaScript to php